# How can i get available height in kendo grid ?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, grid

How can i get available height  in **kendo grid** ?  That means I am adding items dynamically to the grid, So i need height of the grid dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query it by asking the `height` of the `wrapper` (full grid) or `tbody` (inner body of the grid) depending what you want:

```
// Get a reference to the KendoUI Grid object
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
// Ask the height of the Grid
alert("Height of Grid: " + grid.wrapper.height())
// Ask the height of the body (total rows) of the Grid
alert("Height of the body of the Grid: " + grid.tbody.height());
```

Important: the body of the grid might be greater than the Grid itself if part of the rows are hidden and you have to scroll to see them.

Example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#show").on("click", function() {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    alert("Grid: " + grid.wrapper.height() + "\n" + 
          "Body: " + grid.tbody.height());
  });
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: products,
      schema: {
        model: {
          fields: {
            ProductName: { type: "string" },
            UnitPrice: { type: "number" },
            UnitsInStock: { type: "number" },
            Discontinued: { type: "boolean" }
          }
        }
      },
      pageSize: 20
    },
    pageable: true,
    height: 300,

    columns: [
      "ProductName",
      { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "130px" },
      { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: "130px" },
      { field: "Discontinued", width: "130px" }
    ]
  });
});
```

```css
html { font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/shared/js/products.js"></script>


<button id="show" class="k-button">Show</button>
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: @oneBai , In my case , grid height is fixed (eg:370px) and i got the body  height as 345px(Dynamically fixed by kendo)  , first 50px my first record is occupied ,Now i need remaining height of the grid

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `tbody` shows the height of the space used by current rows. If you add new rows and ask again you will have the new height. If you want the difference just subtract one from the other. If you want the height of row `3` do: `$(grid.tbody[0].rows[3]).height()`